# How can I create a link to my app's home page after the user saves input to core data in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on an iOS app in Swift as a personal project to learn iOS/mobile dev. It is an inventory tracking system where the user inputs their own stock, which is then displayed.

Working on the `AddInventoryView`, which is accessed via a `NavigationStack` in `InventoryView`. Once in `AddInventoryView`, I want the user to be able to add details and then save new inventory to the app - I only want the save button/label/text to appear when all fields have been filled out in `AddInventoryView`, and when the user taps save, I want inventory to be saved to core data and the view to be reset to `InventoryView`. I am struggling to set up a button/label/string that *both* saves and links to another view. Inventory is being saved to core data.

AddInventoryView:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddInventoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State var name = ""
    @State var cost = ""
    @State var volume = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            NavigationStack {
                Form {
                //section with TextField's storing input
                }
                .navigationTitle("Add Inventory")
            }
            // if/else to only display once TextField's have values
            if(name != "" && cost != "" && volume != "") {
                Button("Save") {
                    self.saveInventory(name: name, cost: cost, volume: volume)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveInventory(name: String, cost: String, volume: String) {
    // Save input to core data func
    }
}
```

I have tried to use NavigationLink instead of a button, but then I struggle to save to core data. Using NavigationLink also makes it difficult to *only* display once fields are filled out, unless I should be using a method better than an if/else to display the button. I am having the most trouble finding a way to link back to InventoryView **and** saving to core data. It doesn't have to be a button, but I would like it to be.

Comment: You use `NavigationStack` at the top of the hierarchy unless it's a sheet.  The title should come from the parent.

Comment: Do you mean that I should be including my button inside of `NavigationStack`  when you say top of the hierarchy?

Comment: InventoryView doesn't need a button for transition to AddInventoryView as long as the former has `NavigationLink` with its destination pointing to AddInventoryView.

Comment: Oh I see. The question is about the reverse. I want the user to add information within AddInventoryView which then saves to core data and then transitions back to InventoryView.

Comment: If InventoryView has `NavigationLink` for transition to AddInventoryView, you will see the back button.

Comment: I do have that within AddInventoryView. I am trying add the ability for the user to enter details when inside AddInventoryView, then click a Save button, which saves to core data and transitions back to InventoryView.

Comment: If you mean that you want the app to automatically go back to InventoryView after tapping the Save button in the Add guy, then use `NavigationStack` with `.navigationDestination(isPresented:)` in InventoryView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using the `NavigationStack` in the parent view and `dismiss`
in the child view `save` Button to transition back.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <--- here
            NavigationLink(destination: AddInventoryView()) {
                Text("Add to Inventory")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddInventoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss  // <--- here
    
    @State var name = ""
    @State var cost = ""
    @State var volume = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("name", text: $name)
            TextField("cost", text: $cost)
            TextField("volume", text: $volume)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add Inventory")
        // if/else to only display once TextField's have values
        if(!name.isEmpty && !cost.isEmpty && !volume.isEmpty ) {
            Button("Save") {
                self.saveInventory(name: name, cost: cost, volume: volume)
                dismiss() // <--- here
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveInventory(name: String, cost: String, volume: String) {
        // Save input to core data func
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

You can also use another approach using `NavigationPath`.
See:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/#Manage-navigation-state

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var path = NavigationPath()  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){  // <--- here
            NavigationLink(value: "add") {
                Text("Add to Inventory")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { _ in
                AddInventoryView(path: $path)  // <--- here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddInventoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath  // <--- here
    
    @State var name = ""
    @State var cost = ""
    @State var volume = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("name", text: $name)
            TextField("cost", text: $cost)
            TextField("volume", text: $volume)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add Inventory")
        // if/else to only display once TextField's have values
        if(!name.isEmpty && !cost.isEmpty && !volume.isEmpty ) {
            Button("Save") {
                self.saveInventory(name: name, cost: cost, volume: volume)
                path = NavigationPath() // <--- here, go to wherever you want
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveInventory(name: String, cost: String, volume: String) {
        // Save input to core data func
    }
}
```

Using a `Save` button is old fashion to me. I would package
`name`, `cost` and `volume` into an entity and use that.
See this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and it is working as desired. Thank you!

Is this the goal of dismiss()? Is the environment variable needed because it going to another view? 

Do you think there is a better way to accomplish my goal here, specifically referring to my if/else statement with the button only displaying when fields are filled out?

Comment: yes, this is what `dismiss` does. Updated my answer with another approach to navigate to
 wherever you want.